# jQuery-UI Tabs - How to change effects?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm looking to add a nicer effect to a jQuery Content slider which uses tabs.

At the moment it uses 'opacity' which is really ugly.

Here is my code;

```
 $('#featured').tabs({
                      fx:{
                          opacity: "toggle"
                         }
                     }).tabs('rotate', 5000, true);
```

Check out http://www.jsfiddle.net/cxNj8/4/

Is it possible to add a nicer fade like 'fade' in jQuery cycle?

(note: I've added the cycle library to the jsfiddle example)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI tabs doesn't seem to support "crossfading", only "fade out" then "fade in" with a blank gap between them.

However, you might try the Flowplayer jQuery plugin which has an example of doing cross-fading tabs in a slideshow that is similar to your example:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/slideshow.html

Comment: Jeff, that's a useful resource.

Thanks for flagging this up. Hopefully this can be used in some way to improve the tabs effects.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#featured').tabs({
                      fx:{
                           height: "toggle",
                           opacity: 'toggle', 
                           duration: 600   
                         }
                     }).tabs('rotate', 5000, true);
```